# Disable Calender date from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using ASP calender and 
I want to disable all those date in my database in my calender how can I do that?

I am using dataset to get the date from database for those non Available date.

I got error:
Object must be of type DateTime
here is my code:

if (e.Day.Date.CompareTo("Non_Available") == 0) 
{ e.Day.IsSelectable = false; }

Comment: What differentiates an available date from an unavailable one?

Comment: Those available date can let the person to choose and those unavailable  date is mean that those date have been pick by another person

Comment: Is there any wrong with my code?

Comment: check e.day.date which format and then convert your dataset value that format

Comment: need help in this error

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're getting the dates from the database with a DataSet. You'd have to set up the DayRender event of the calendar. In there you can loop through the dates from the DataSet and then set e.Day.IsSelectable = false. So Something like this:

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.Date.CompareTo(DateTime.Today) == 0)
    {
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
    }
}
```

You'd just replace the DateTime.Today with the value from the DB.

Comment: Yes I using DateSet to get the date from database
I got error say the Object must be of type DateTime

My code


 if (e.Day.Date.CompareTo("Non_Available") == 0)
        {
            e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        }

Comment: Generally one would use the Convert class to convert the value of a DataColumn to what they want. `Convert.ToDateTime(DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"].ToString())` for example. Save that value to a DateTime variable and use it in the compare. "Non_Available" will through an error because it's of type String and not a DateTime.